# Why is my Firebase Authentication function not working anymore?

Tags: typescript, firebase, ionic-framework, firebase-authentication

I wrote this Fire Auth function a couple months ago, but when I tried it today, it returned me the following error:

> ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'uid' of null

I can't seem to figure out where I went wrong because I haven't altered any of the code.

The user is successfully signed in according to the Firebase Console.

Code:

login.ts followed by login.html

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicPage, NavController, ToastController, NavParams } from 'ionic-angular';

//Firebase imports
import { AngularFireAuth } from 'angularfire2/auth';

//Model import
import { User } from '../../models/user.interface';

//Page import 
import { HomePage } from '../home/home';

@IonicPage()
@Component({
  selector: 'page-login',
  templateUrl: 'login.html',
})
export class LoginPage {

  oldUser = {} as User;

  constructor(
    private afAuth: AngularFireAuth,
    public navCtrl: NavController, 
    public navParams: NavParams,
    private toast: ToastController) {
  }

  async login(oldUser: User) {
    try {
      const result = this.afAuth.auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(oldUser.email, oldUser.password);
      if (result) {
        this.navCtrl.setRoot(HomePage);
        this.toast.create({
          message: `We're all given the same hours in a day. Are you ready to maximise yours?`,
          duration: 3000
        }).present();
      } 
    }
    catch(e) {
      this.toast.create({
        message:   `Let's try again: ` + `${e}`.substr(7),
        duration: 2000
      }).present();
    }
  }
}
```

```html
    <div class="list">
      <ion-item>
        <ion-input class="title" type="email" placeholder="Email Address" [(ngModel)]="oldUser.email"></ion-input>
      </ion-item>
    
      <ion-item>
        <ion-input class="title" placeholder="Password" clear-input type="password" [(ngModel)]="oldUser.password"></ion-input>
      </ion-item>
    </div>
    
    <button ion-button (click)="login(oldUser)">LOGIN</button>
```

Please help!! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

u need to check if the user exist 1 then do yourlogic

```
 let user = this.fireAuth.auth.currentUser;
    if (user != null) {
      currentUser.id = user.uid;
      currentUser.email = user.email;
      // login logic ...
    }
```

more info [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/manage-users)

Comment: Thanks Kevin. I was primarily concerned because the same code has been running for four months, but just suddenly stopped working. My dev environment is the same, too...

Comment: np , but  if 'uid' is null the user dont exist on db or has been deleted

Comment: I tried exactly the method that you used, but it still does not work! It's very odd because the user exists in my database and is clearly being logged in (the most recent login is documented in my database).

Comment: mmmm it may exist on your database but does it exist on Authentication DB  on users? check it  pls